# Webkit scrollLeft + CSS translate horizontal bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, css-transforms

I have a DOM structure like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Container is a scrollable element with style `overflow:scroll`. Content has specified width and height.

## Specific situation (possible webkit bug)

When Container is scrolled rightmost (visible right border of the content) and I apply `transform: translateX(-100px)` on the content element, behaviour is different in different browsers (see Results).

## Results

- Firefox/Opera/Edge: content is translated 100px left. Visible background of the container.
- Webkit/Chrome: content isn't translated at all. Not visible background of the container. Horizontal scroll width is changed.

**What can be done to achieve normalized result, which is translated content and visible background of the container?** (like Firefox/Opera/Edge)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh6wt1r1/)

```js
 const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
 const content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
 container.scrollLeft = 1400;
 content.style.transform = 'translateX(-100px)';
```

```css
.container {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: gray;
 left: calc(50% - 200px);
 top: calc(50% - 150px);
 overflow: scroll;
 position: relative;
}

.content {
 width: 1400px;
 height: 1400px;
 background: radial-gradient(at center center, red 0%, lightgreen 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Firefox, it was as you described it, but when I opened the Developer Tools I got the same behavior as Chrome's. I'm using Firefox 58.0.2.

Comment: I tried a few more things and the behavior is really not consistant. I don't think this is related to WebKit. Were you looking for a solution or just wanted to report this behavior?

Comment: I would love to get to know a solution. My attempts to get rid of this bug were failed. Of course, reporting this strange behaviour is also important.

Comment: I agree that someone should look into that. The solution is very simple: You can add a CSS class and apply it through JavaScript. Let me know if you have any trouble with that.

Comment: It cannot be done with "very simple solution" using classes. Literally, you can't translate `Content` element beyond the right edge of the `Container` (`dir="ltr"`). The same, but with left edge when direction is set to rtl (`dir="rtl"`).